# Android stretches the layout file instead of loading the correct file in the res folders

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a handset version of an activity and a tablet version of the same activity. My handset version is  `res/layout/activity.xml` while my 7' tablet version is `res/layout-sw600dp/activity.xml`

The thing is that when I run the app in a 7' tablet, not only does it not load the xml file in `res/layout-sw600dp`, but it displays a stretched version of the layout in the `res/layout` folder. So, everything from buttons, images, as well as the action bar itself is simply stretched and distorted to fill the whole screen (much the same way an iPad displays the 2X version of an iPhone app).

I was using Android Studio and it was working fine, but I had to switch to Eclipse for reasons which aren't relevant, so I suspect it might be something related to Eclipse's configuration, but it's just a wild guess.

I've never had this issue before. Has anyone ever experienced this and found a solution? Thanks.

pd. If I use Eclipse's layout editor and select "Preview all sizes", it actually loads the correct xml into the 7' and the 10' previews.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. What was causing this weird behavior is that I was missing the following attributes in my `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9"
      android:targetSdkVersion="19"
      android:maxSdkVersion="19" />
```

Comment: I'm using Android Studio, but specifying sdk version doesn't work.